# LINQ to get the Descendant of type "a" from HTMLNodesCollection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, html-agility-pack

I have a colectionof HTML nodes:

```
 var imageColletion = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d =>     
d.Attributes.Contains("Class") && d.Attributes["Class"].Value.
Contains("entry-thumbnail hover-thumb")).Select(x => x.ChildNodes);
```

Now from imageColletion I want to get the "a".Tried with

```
    var allImages = imageColletion.Select(nodeCollection => 
  nodeCollection.Descendants("a"));
```

Here I am not getting any outputs. What wrong with my query?

[image]

**EDIT1:**
     HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);

```
  var headerCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("h2").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("Class") && d.Attributes["Class"].Value.Contains("entry-title")).Select(x => x.ChildNodes);
  var titleCollection = headerCollection.Select(x => x.Select(y => y.InnerHtml).Where(strValue=>strValue!="\n").FirstOrDefault());

 var imageColletion = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("Class") && d.Attributes["Class"].Value.Contains("entry-thumbnail hover-thumb")).Select(x => x.ChildNodes);
                //var allImages = imageColletion.Select(nodeCollection => nodeCollection.Select(x => x.InnerHtml).Where(imgstring=>imgstring.Contains("img")));
 var allImages = imageColletion.Select(nodeCollection => nodeCollection.Descendants("a"));
```

HTML:

```
<div class="entry-thumbnail hover-thumb">
<a href="/" title="Actions for Photographers" rel="bookmark">
<img src="img" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Free for Photographers"> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the data that you're working with, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: @JeffMercado,Posted the Code.Hope this Helps

Comment: The code doesn't say much about what you're working with, _maybe_ what you're trying to get. But it doesn't help if we don't know what the html looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your html, this works

```
var imgElems = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
               .SelectNodes("//div[@class='entry-thumbnail hover-thumb']/a/img");
```

I don't see any **H** element as your title says...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're selecting all children of the div.  You either have to filter it or specifically get the `h` children.

```
....Select(x => x.ChildNodes.Where(y => y.Name == "a"));
```

```
....Select(x => x.Elements("a"));
```

I would have used an xpath query myself.

```
var xpath =
   "//div[contains(@class,'entry-thumbnail')][contains(@class,'hover-thumb')]/a";
var query = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

Comment: Well what do you expect? You posed one question in your title looking for "h" elements so I gave you the answer for that. But the body of your question asks for a different element. Then you left out all the critical details like what the data you actually have looks like. Then take the answer literally. _You_ should have seen that and corrected it, not _me_ or anyone else, **YOU**.